# How to return a File using Open XML in ASP.NET and VB.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a legacy ASP.NET 3.5 (NOT ASP.NET MVC )application using VB.NET. I want to download an excel spreadsheet when a user clicks on a button.I am using OpenXML library. I have used the same feature in ASP.NET MVC where you could return a file using OpenXML like this:-

```
public FileContentResult GetCollectionsExcel()
{
    var collections = CurrentBroker.Collections;

            var model = new FinancialCollectionsModel(collections);

            var package = new ExcelPackage();
            var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Collections");

   return File(package.GetAsByteArray(),"application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheet.sheet", "Collections.xlsx");
}
```

What would be it's equivalent in traditional ASP.NET and VB.NET ? What should be the return type of the method as we don't have a FileContentResult in ASP.NET.

Comment: Access the response directly, write the data to the response stream and set the necessary headers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the response directly, write the data to the response stream and set the necessary headers

```vb
'...code removed for brevity

Dim response = HttpContext.Current.Response
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheet.sheet"
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""Collections.xlsx""")
response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray())
```